# Random record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Now i am making a web application (Online word learning) that allow user to choose the correct meaning of the word. When they click start, it will select randomly one word from the database and show to the user. After the user choose the answer, it will go to the next question.
Please see the image below:
[image]

If i use, Word.order("rand()").limit(1), i wonder can the word will be repeated with the last selected word?
With the app as in the image above, any better ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with *"can the word will be repeated"*. Do you want to repeat the last word? Or do your want to avoid repetition that may happen accidentally when you use random ordering?

Comment: I want to avoid repetition

Comment: With the problem as image above, can you suggest me some better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following scopes to the model (depends on the database you are using):

```
# in app/models/word.rb
# 'RANDOM' works with postgresql and sqlite, whereas mysql uses 'RAND'
scope :random, -> { order('RAND()') }
scope :without, ->(ids) { where.not(id: ids) }
```

With that scopes you can write the following query in your controller:

```
@word = Word.random.without(params[:last_ids]).limit(1)
```

When you want to load new random elements in the view, just add the ids of the current words to the request. This ensures that this ids (`params[:last_ids]`) are not randomly choosen.

Comment: But example after i choose 3 words already, so can it repeat with the first selected word?

Comment: It absolutely would be repeated. This is a really good solution if you have a large data set, say over 10,000, but will be more obvious on a much smaller data set. To do something more clever would require tracking which cards have been seen and excluding those. You could add that to the session pretty easily.

Comment: By choosing all four words at once with `limit(4)`.

Comment: How to add that to session? can you show me an example?

Comment: i want only to limit(1), when the user choose the answer, i will next to the next random record.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, in order not to repeat yourself, you have to store those words somewhere. Either the ones that are yet to be shown, or the ones that have been already displayed. And If I were you I would go one of the following routes:

1. Fetch all the words before starting the quiz and randomize them. This could be something like:

   ```
   session[:words] = Word.order("RAND()").select(:id).take(10)
   ```

   Or even better by defining a scope for your random words:

   ```
   class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
     # ...
     scope :random_quiz, -> { order("RAND()").take(10).pluck(:id) }
     # ...
   end

   # ... in the controller when the quiz is getting started:
   session[:words] = Word.random_quiz
   # ... in the controller when you want to show the word:
   new_word = Word.find(sessions[:words].pop)
   ```

   As `ORDER BY RAND()` is a very expensive operation, this might make sense. And then you just pop the word ID's one by one by using `session[:words].pop` and present the questions.

   This way it will guarantee that you won't repeat the words in the quiz and give you pretty optimal performance.
2. Fetch words one by one as you're progressing with giving out the questions and save the ones you've already asked about.

   ```
   class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
     # ...
     def self.random_word(exclusions)
       eligible = where('id NOT IN (?)', exclusions)
       eligible.offset(rand(0..eligible.count)).take!(1)
     end
     # ..
   end

   # ... in the controller when you need a new word:
   session[:words_shown] ||= [ ]
   new_word = Word.random_word(session[:words_shown])
   # mark the word as shown:
   session[:words_shown].push(new_word.id)
   ```

You might have noticed the weird way of getting a random record in the second example. It turns out to be more efficient as it generates the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM words OFFSET _random_number_ LIMIT 1
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

The first one is just an ordinary select, while the second one requires unindexed sorting by `RAND()` of the entire table before giving you that random result. Turns out to be the former is almost tenfold faster than the latter.

Hope that makes sense!